# Transpose Sql to Mongo : group by grandparent id, show last child and parent id using, group by max

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am a beginner in mongodb and have a sql query I would like to convert and am having trouble.

This sql will give you the last child that was created per grandparent. Each child was entered into the table in sequence.

```
select parent.grandparent_id, parent.id , max(child.id) 
from parent
join child on child.parent_id = parent.id
group by parent.grandparent_id
```

In mongodb I have a document with structure:

```
grandparent_id, parent_id, child_id
```

The closest I got was:

```
db.forum_topic_post_stats.aggregate([
{$group: {_id: "$grandparent_id", last_grandchild: { $max: "$child_id" } } },
])
```

What I am having great trouble with is getting access to the parent_id because the document returned only gives:

```
_id: <$grandparent_id>
last_grandchild: <$child_id>
```

How do I show the parent? I have tried using project but when i specify the parent the result is null.

Any ideas?

Comment: There are no "joins" in Mongo as it's document-oriented storage. Next, aggregation is implemented with additional framework which has certain limitation (but your case will fit into it well). Due to this - are you really sure you want to migrate from RDBMS to document-oriented storage?

Comment: Also I realised that in the sql example I can take advantage of the 3 table structure. In the mongodb example there is no hierarchy so can I embed documents? This isn't for migration. Its for tracking and avoiding multi-join queries in mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is relational, but that does not mean you cannot fit it into MongoDB.

What I assume your data looks like is this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a7c3bba13242e55e3a8848"),
    "parent_id" : 245,
    "parent" : "John doe",
    "grandparent_id" : 1,
    "child_id" : 34
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55a7c3cfa13242e55e3a8849"),
    "parent_id" : 246,
    "parent" : "Johnny Doe",
    "grandparent_id" : 2,
    "child_id" : 36
}
```

You were pretty close with your query. Try running this to keep the parent_id in the key.

```
 db.parent.aggregate([{$group: { _id: { grandparent: "$grandparent_id", parent: "$parent_id"}, last_grandchild: { $max: "$child_id" } } } ])
```

Which finally gives this result:

```
{ "_id" : { "grandparent" : 2, "parent" : 246 }, "last_grandchild" : 36 }
{ "_id" : { "grandparent" : 1, "parent" : 245 }, "last_grandchild" : 34 }
```

Comment: I need the the last child to be born per grandparent. So the youngest child from that grandparent. Your query gives me the youngest child per parent and also gives the grandparent details.